# How to add static function to a class on run time?

Tags: typescript

I wrote a **class decorator** like in this example below (**which works**):

```
function WrapIt(options) {
  return (klass: any) => {
    var newConstructor = function () {
      return new klass.apply(null, arguments);
    };
    newConstructor.prototype = klass.prototype;

    // THIS must work as a static function in the output class
    newConstructor.factory = (amount: number) => {
      var newObj;
      var list = [];
      for (var n=0; n<amount; n++) {
        newObj = new klass();
        newObj.name = '#' + n + ': ' + newObj.selector();
        list.push(newObj);
      }

      return list;
    };

    return newConstructor;

    // return <typeof klass> newConstructor;
    /* The way commented above shows these warnings:
    [default] /.../decorators.ts:16:24 
      Property 'factory' does not exist on type '() => any'.
    */
  }
}

@WrapIt({
  option1: 'yay'
})
class Dog {
  selector() {
    return 'a dog'
  }
}

@WrapIt({
  option1: 'yay'
})
class Cat {
  selector() {
    return 'a cat'
  }
}
```

You can also see it in action here: http://plnkr.co/edit/tAXMOt?p=preview

But despite it works, TypeScript compiler insists on these warnings:

```
[default] /.../my-classes.ts:11:1 
  Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'void'.

[default] /.../decorators.ts:13:24 
  Property 'factory' does not exist on type '() => void'.
```

It's annoying to the see the warnings, so, what am I doing wrong? How can I make TS compiler happy?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working and compiling ok:

```
type DogConstructor = {
    new(): Dog;
};

function WrapIt(options) {
    return (klass: typeof Dog): DogConstructor => {
        var newConstructor = function () {
            return (klass.apply(null, arguments) as DogConstructor);
        } as any;
        newConstructor.prototype = klass.prototype;

        newConstructor.factory = (amount: number) => {
            var newObj;
            var list = [];
            for (var n = 0; n < amount; n++) {
                newObj = new klass();
                newObj.name = '#' + n + ': ' + newObj.selector();
                list.push(newObj);
            }

            return list;
        };

        return newConstructor;
    }
}

@WrapIt({
    option1: 'yay'
})
class Dog {
    selector() {
        return 'a dog'
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20DogConstructor%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09new()%3A%20Dog%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20WrapIt(options)%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20(klass%3A%20typeof%20Dog)%3A%20DogConstructor%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09var%20newConstructor%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09return%20(klass.apply(null%2C%20arguments)%20as%20DogConstructor)%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%09%09newConstructor.prototype%20%3D%20klass.prototype%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%09newConstructor.factory%20%3D%20(amount%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09var%20newObj%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09var%20list%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09for%20(var%20n%20%3D%200%3B%20n%20%3C%20amount%3B%20n%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09newObj%20%3D%20new%20klass()%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09newObj.name%20%3D%20'%23'%20%2B%20n%20%2B%20'%3A%20'%20%2B%20newObj.selector()%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09list.push(newObj)%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%09return%20list%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09return%20newConstructor%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40WrapIt(%7B%0D%0A%09option1%3A%20'yay'%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0Aclass%20Dog%20%7B%0D%0A%09selector()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20'a%20dog'%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D))

The only hack that was needed is the casting of the `newConstructor` to `any`.